# Selfmade iterator over a set in Java

Tags: java, iterator, set

In preparation for my exams I'm writing a few of the old exams that were given to us. In one of them we have to Implement an EnterpriseNode. One task is to write an iterator that iterates over the Staffmembers. I wrote the function next() but it doesn't work properly.
This is my code:

```
public StaffMemberIterator(HashSet<StaffMember> directSubordinates){
        if(directSubordinates == null) throw new NullPointerException("ofs");
        this.directSubordinates = directSubordinates;
    }


public StaffMember next() {
        if (!this.hasNext()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("naf");
        }
        ArrayList<StaffMember> subList = new ArrayList<>(directSubordinates);
        StaffMember staffMember = subList.get(position);
        position++;
        return staffMember;
    }
```

and this is the error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: StaffMemberIterator.next() should return the correct next element if there is one available! expected:<Name: Allie, Job: J1> but was:<Name: Lilith, Job: J3>
    at StaffMemberIteratorTest.testIterator(StaffMemberIteratorTest.java:48)
```

Thank you guys for any help!

Comment: So you have JUnit tests, and aren't leveraging them as much as possible? Have you tried debugging to see what your Iterator does? How does hasNext() work? There's a lot of questions and not a lot of code to work with.

Comment: I don't see anything that imposes a particular order for the set members.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As Klas said in his comment, a `HashSet` doesn't impose any particular order. A `TreeSet` would impose order based on natural ordering or a defined `Comparator`. The order of the values in a `HashSet` will depend on the result of the hash function.

I'm not sure what your exam question is actually looking for, but it would make sense to implement the `Iterator<E>` interface given that you are implementing an iterator in Java.

Example implementation:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;

public class StaffIterator implements Iterator<StaffMember> {

    private final StaffMember[] staffMembers;
    private int index;

    public StaffIterator(Set<StaffMember> staffMembers) {
        this.staffMembers = staffMembers.toArray(new StaffMember[staffMembers.size()]);
        index = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < staffMembers.length;
    }

    @Override
    public StaffMember next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        return staffMembers[index++];
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Note: not terribly efficent as `AbstractCollection.toArray(T[] a)` iterates over the Collection in order to populate the array. But it is certainly more efficient than copying a `Collection` into an `ArrayList` with each `next()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `LinkedHashSet` instead of `HashSet`

If you are not getting the staff member that you expected, it is because `HashSet` does not retain the order of insertion of the elements.  As explained in [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). ***It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.*** This class permits the null element.

[`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) on the other hand, retains the order of insertion. As quoted in the Javadocs:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. ***This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order).*** Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the set.